# Transfer Information from one file to a final one

Tags: excel, vba

I need to develop a VBA code that brings information from a different file (3 different tabs) and combines everything into one final file.

The final file looks like the table below. We have 7 columns (column 3, 4 and 7 have always the same value):
https://www.dropbox.com/s/x0vd84ar5qh8dr3/CustomerAmendments.csv?dl=0

The file from where the information is coming has the previous view:
https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/zii79x0i01wbsti1vfr9c/Combined-amendments.xlsm?dl=0&rlkey=s0oy0uy26ej3fwhewzfd2zyct

Steps of the macro:

1- Filter in tabs "NI" and "ROI" column R by "C" and copy the information from columns C, D, I and P;

2- Filter in tab "OCADO" column Q by "C" and copy the information from columns C, D, I and O;

3- Paste information on the final file according with by column order shown in the final file.

I developed the below code but I get an error could you please have a look?

```
   Sub CustomerAmends()
Dim sh As Worksheet, ary As Variant, i As Long
Set sh = Workbooks("X:\Planning\production plans\production plans\Order Amendments\Combined amendments.xlsm").Sheets(1) 

ary = Array("NI", "ROI", "OCADO")
    For i = LBound(ary) To UBound(ary)
        With Sheets(ary(i))
            .UsedRange.AutoFilter 17, "C"
            .Range("C2", .Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp)).Copy sh.Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp)(2)
            .Range("D2", .Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp)).Copy sh.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)(2)
            .Range("I2", .Cells(Rows.Count, 9).End(xlUp)).Copy sh.Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp)(2)
                If i <> UBound(ary) Then
                    .Range("P2", .Cells(Rows.Count, 16).End(xlUp)).Copy sh.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp)(2)
                Else
                    .Range("O2", .Cells(Rows.Count, 15).End(xlUp)).Copy sh.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp)(2)
                End If
            .AutoFilterMode = False
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

Thank you! :)

Comment: "I get an error" is not a very useful description of the problem you're having.  What error do you get, and on which line?

Comment: Hi there! The error I get is on the third line - location of the file. The issue is Peh that the information should come from "combined amendments.xlsm" and the information shoult be pasted on the file "Customer amends.xlsm" which is the host file. I don't know how to put that in va code :/

Comment: If the destination workbook isn't open then you'll need to open it.  If it is already open then you can use `Set sh = Workbooks("Combined amendments.xlsm").Sheets(1)`